# I am using highcharts that give data when I insert in array but I want to insert data dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to make this data dynamically added to highcharts instead of the custom array? Is it possible to use each loop to insert data dynamically? Is there any way that we can use table or another array to make it dynamically? As i am new in highcharts so i can't figure out how to use that.
Thanks in advance

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo',
        align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mb',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || // theme
            'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mb'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' °C'
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` or `setData` method to add series / data to the already existing chart:

```
$.getJSON( "...", function( data ) {
  chart.series[0].setData(data);
});

// OR

$.getJSON( "...", function( data ) {
  chart.update({
    series: [{
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4948/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

---

Or create a chart when the data finished loading:

```
$.getJSON( "...", function( data ) {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4949/

---

You can also use Highcharts data module: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro and get data for example from CSV.